# Python 2.7: csv.gz file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, gzip

I have a file.csv.gz and I have a local string variable of an ip address that I am trying to compare to a value in the file and then print the corresponding value in the first column. I know the value will be in column 2 of the file and am hoping to make this work without having to decompress the file manually. I think I have most of this correct, (hopefully?). However, I am getting the following error:

"csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?"

```
import csv
import gzip

checklist = []
if val = '67.49.159.35'
with gzip.open('path', mode='rb') as f:
    tcsv = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for col in tcsv:
        checklist = [col[0], col[1]]
            if val == checklist[1]:
                print checklist[0]
```

I am wondering exactly what I am doing wrong. I have tried replace mode='rb' to 'rU' but to no avail. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I should have specified but I have to do this on multiple files.

Comment: Please `print` the `repr` of a few lines without the `csv.reader` to see what they look like raw.

Comment: Have you considered decompressing the files in a separate script (perhaps in bash)? Perhaps the `gzip` and `csv` modules do not play well together.

Comment: what if you just open it for reading? like `r` no bytes or U.